# Properties of outer-measure and subsets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $B\subseteq A$ and $\mu^*$ is an outer-measure, then is it true to say
$$
\mu^*(A\setminus B) = \mu^*(A) -\mu^*(B)
$$

Here's my reasoning as to why I think it is.

$$A = B \cup (A\setminus B)$$
Thus,
$$\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(B \cup (A\setminus B))$$

But, $B$ and $A\setminus B$ are disjoint, thus $\mu^*(B \cup (A\setminus B)) = \mu^*(B) + \mu^*(A\setminus B)$. Hence,

$$\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(B) + \mu^*(A\setminus B)$$

Then, we rearrange to get
$$ \mu^*(A\setminus B) = \mu^*(A) -\mu^*(B)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You argue that $$\mu^*(B\cup(A\setminus B))=\mu^*(B)+\mu^*(A\setminus B)$$ because $B$ and $A\setminus B$ are disjoint. However, this is not a property of outer measures. Generally you only have the inequality $$\mu^*(B\cup(A\setminus B))\leq\mu^*(B)+\mu^*(A\setminus B).$$ So your calculations would lead to  $$\mu^*(A\setminus B)\geq\mu^*(A)-\mu^*(B).$$